# Accessing backend server endpoint at runtime in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tomcat, nginx, web-applications

I have a react application which gets served from ngnix server. This app hits an apache backend server to fetch data and use that data to create UI.

I configured two endpoints for my application, dev nginx and prod nginx. Now what I want is, when this application gets served from dev nginx server, then I want it to pick a dev endpoint of the backend tomcat server and when it gets served by prod nginx server I want it to pick the production tomcat server endpoint.

How can I inject this backend server endpoint in my react application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for this problem is https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: This requires UI bundle rebuild, while John Girata response allows to change API server URL _after_ (and independent of) the UI build.

Pretty much in a runtime of a web server, serving static UI files.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options.  Here are a few of the simpler ones:

1. Presumably you have at least one HTML file that is the landing page of your app.  You can generate two sets of HTML files: one for dev, and one for production.  Each set of HTML files would contain a JS variable indicating the environment.
2. You can run a script before starting the nginx servers that modifies the HTML files and injects a variable (or, really, just the value of the variable) with environment information.
3. If you don't want to modify the HTML file dynamically, you can create a simple JS file that just assigns a variable to the global scope with the environment information.  Then your HTML file can load this (via a `<script>` tag) before loading the rest of your app.
4. You can guess the Apache hostname based on the nginx hostname (e.g., via `window.location.host`).

Comment: Looks like injecting dynamically is a good solution. Will try that